# Nagios Core - How can I show the graph icons up with pnp4nagios?

Tags: ubuntu, server, monitoring, nagios

My Nagios Core server is an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS device,
I installed pnp4nagios plugins and it works well, the graphs are displaying on the "http://@IP/pnp4nagios/" page.

However, I'm trying to put the graph icons on Nagios Core (in the Services menu)
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I569I.png) but I don't know how to do it.

So please, I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you experiment with the `action_url` attribute which is available for service and host objects. The [description from the manual](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html) is:

> This directive is used to define an optional URL that can be used to provide more actions to be performed on the host. If you specify an URL, you will see a red "splat" icon in the CGIs (when you are viewing host information) that links to the URL you specify here. (...)

This attribute supports [macros](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/macrolist.html), so you should be able to set a value **like** (host example):

```
action_url  http://your_host/pnp4nagios/$HOSTNAME$
```

I don't know what the correct syntax would be for your pnp4nagios instance, but this way you can have Nagios fill in the dynamic part of the URL for you, and as such the attribute can be re-used across many objects (through a template for example).